# Why does my apache camel split/aggregate route return no results?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to read a binary file, convert it into a pojo format and then output as CSV. The unmarshalling (and marshalling) seems to be fine, but I'm having trouble optimising the converting the relevant records to `Foo.class`. The attempt below returns no results.

```
from(String.format("file://%s?move=%s", INPUT_DIRECTORY, MOVE_DIRECTORY))
    .unmarshal(unmarshaller)
    .split(bodyAs(Iterator.class), new ListAggregationStrategy())
        .choice()
            .when(not(predicate)).stop()
            .otherwise().convertBodyTo(Foo.class)
        .end()
    .end()
    .marshal(csv)
    .to(String.format("file://%s?fileName=${header.CamelFileName}.csv", OUTPUT_DIRECTORY));
```

I was able to get it to work like this, but it feels like there has to be a better way - This will be need to be efficient, and having a 1s timeout feels like it goes against that, which is why I was attempting to use the built in `split` aggregation. Alternatively some way of using `completionFromBatchConsumer`, but I was struggling to make that work either!.

```
from(String.format("file://%s?move=%s", INPUT_DIRECTORY, MOVE_DIRECTORY))
    .unmarshal(unmarshaller)
    .split(bodyAs(Iterator.class))
        .streaming()
        .filter(predicate)
            .convertBodyTo(Foo.class)
            .aggregate(header("CamelFileName"), new ListAggregationStrategy())
            .completionTimeout(1000)
            .marshal(csv)
            .to(String.format("file://%s?fileName=${header.CamelFileName}.csv", OUTPUT_DIRECTORY));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own AggregationStrategy in your first solution.
Instead of calling stop() in your choice statement, put a simple header like "skipMerge" to true.
In your strategy, test if this header exists and if so, skip it.

```
class ArrayListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        Boolean skipMerge = newExchange.getIn().getHeader("skipMerge", Boolean.class);

        if (!skipMerge) { return oldExchange; }
        ArrayList<Object> list = null;
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.add(newBody);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
            list.add(newBody);
            return oldExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, your code never goes to marshal(csv) because the aggregator does not receive all the splitted parts.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In the end I didn't add a header, instead just had an `instanceof Foo` check.